# angular hide if object property is another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my ngController I loop over an objects propertys which can be a value or an object.
My object

```
   _{
    "_id":"12545",
    "createdBy":{"_id":"someid","name":"somename"},
    "createdOn":"2016-05-13T14:34:47.322Z",
    "item":{"id":"1235561","name":"track"},
    "players":[{"_id":"someid","name":"somename"}],
    "maxPlayers":4,
    "minPlayers":1,
     "state":"open"}
```

To loop the propertys I use

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in game">
   <b>{{key}}</b> - {{value}}
 </div>
```

Now I just want to show the property which are values and not objects.
so I **want** to show _id, _createdOn, maxPlayers, minPlayers, state but **not** createdBy, item, players.

How can I do a check to see if it is an object and then hide it, I tried:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in game" ng-hide="isObject(value)">
    <b>{{key}}</b> - {{value}}
</div>
```

--

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in game" ng-hide="{{isObject(value)}}">
    <b>{{key}}</b> - {{value}}
</div>
```

also tried:

```
 value.isObject();
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$scope.isObject = function(obj) {
    return (typeof obj === 'object');
  };
```

Example:https://jsfiddle.net/ofL9zvuL/1/

Comment: How is this not an answer?

Comment: That is the answer, not sure what else I have to add. Since Sven used a function name called isObject, I had defined the same function with the solution. I guess there should not be any confusion or require more details to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always move the ng-hide off of the ng-repeated element:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
  <div ng-hide='isObject(value)'>
    <b>{{key}}</b> - {{value}}
  </div>
</div>

$scope.isObject = function(value) {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution here. I am using ng-show instead. And it is working when on the ng-repeat div.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mlhuff12/rbo1b9qd/5/)

```
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in game" ng-show="isObject(value)">
      <b>{{key}}</b> - {{value}}
  </div>

  $scope.game = {
"_id": "12545",
"createdBy": {
  "_id": "someid",
  "name": "somename"
},
"createdOn": "2016-05-13T14:34:47.322Z",
"item": {
  "id": "1235561",
  "name": "track"
},
"players": [{
  "_id": "someid",
  "name": "somename"
}],
"maxPlayers": 4,
"minPlayers": 1,
"state": "open"
};



$scope.isObject = function(value) {
    return typeof value == 'object';
  };
```